# Built-in operations in TensorFlow Lite delegated to NNAPI are far less than those defined in NeuralNetworks.h

Tags: tensorflow

As title,

Code for delegation.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/nnapi_delegate.cc#L133

Operators defined in NNAPI.
https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/neural_networks_8h.html

We(Drivers) accelerate operations defined in NNAPI while many of them won't even be passed down.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that only a subset of operations are passed to NN API. The delegation code is being improved and should solve this problem when it is released. Stay tuned.